# prolog-two lists, do the operation on the corresponding elements

Tags: prolog

I'm good at JAVA,now I'm learning Prolog,its so difficult that i need some help...thank you.
each element of `ABs` is a term of the form A-B where A is the corresponding element of As and B is the corresponding element of `Bs`.

`zip(As,Bs,ABs)`:

some examples:

```
zip([1,2,3,4],[a,b,c,d],L). 
  L=[1-a,2-b,3-c,4-d].

zip(X,Y,[1-a,2-b,3-c]).
  X=[1,2,3],Y=[a,b,c]
zip([1,2,3,4],[a,b,c],L). 
 fail.
```

can someone help me. thank you..

My implementation:

```
zip(As,Bs,ABs) :-
   append(X,XS,As),
   append(Y,YS,Bs),
```

this is what i have done..im lost..

Comment: `combined(A, B, A-B).` then `maplist(combined, As, Bs, ABs).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very efficient to use append/3. You could simply write something like:

```
zip([],[],[]).
zip([H|T],[H1|T1],[H-H1|T2]):-zip(T,T1,T2).
```

Some examples:

```
?- zip([1,2,3,4],[a,b,c,d],L). 
L = [1-a, 2-b, 3-c, 4-d].

?- zip(X,Y,[1-a,2-b,3-c]).
X = [1, 2, 3],
Y = [a, b, c].

?- zip([1,2,3,4],[a,b,c],L). 
false.
```

Comment: thank you so much. helps a lot! i may get some ideas.

Comment: I just did it,I think I made it.anyway ,I'm not familiar with this function.Thank you again;P